# UITableView Not Allowing any Toolbars on the Bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have a view controller that contains a UITableView. I'm trying to put the UITableView into a UITabBarController as one of the views. It wont work, nothing will show up on the bottom. If I put an iAd banner on the bottom, it doesn't show. The UITabBar will not show. I don't know what the problem is. I'm figuring that maybe the UITableView is going somehow over the UITabBar, but I really have no clue. I tried making it shorter, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I'm doing this using UIStoryboards, mainly. I'm not sure what code is relevant here, so please just tell me if you need to see any. Thanks in advance,

-Sam

Comment: I'm not getting the statement, "I'm trying to put the UITableView into a UITabBarController as one of the views."  A tab bar controller manages other controllers, not views.  Assuming this is something you're doing in code, it might be worth looking at.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. I meant to say view controllers.

Comment: It's a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through what you're going through - I'm also using storyboards.  I don't remember where I found this snippet but it has worked well for me.  Credit should go to the guy who wrote it originally.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Initialize the toolbar 
    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init]; 
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    //Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app. 
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    //Caclulate the height of the toolbar CGFloat 
    CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;

    //Get the bounds of the parent view 
    CGRect rootViewBounds = self.parentViewController.view.bounds;

    //Get the height of the parent view. 
    CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);

    //Get the width of the parent view, 
    CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);

    //Create a rectangle for the toolbar 
    CGRect rectArea = CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight - toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight);

    //Reposition and resize the receiver 
    [toolbar setFrame:rectArea];

    // add buttons (make sure you create your buttons)
    //[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trashButtonItem, leftSpaceButtonItem, cameraButtonItem, rightSpaceButtonItem, addButtonItem, nil]];

    //Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller. 
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar]; 

}
```

You'll have to substitute the buttons with your own obviously.

Comment: SportStatTracker[10973:15203] -[UITabBarItem _shouldBezelSystemButtonImage] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Did you remove my ButtonItems and substitute in your own?  On the line below: // add buttons

I left them in for illustration purposes of how to add the buttons, I'll edit the answer and comment that line out.

Comment: Yes. I made the new one like (and this code may not be exact, not in front of my mac) [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarItemStye:UITabBarItemStyleFeatured];

Comment: This also works if you set up your toolbar in UIBuilder and hook a pointer to your code, so you don't have to programmatically build the buttons. You may need to place this code snippet in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewWillAppear as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend your class by UIViewController, not UITableViewController because that takes up your entire view.

Comment: So you will have a normal view, then you add a UITableView to that view, and also the toolbar under it. UITableviewController only does a small bit of work to help you so you don't really miss it. I never use it.